# Error scraping twitter with twitterscraper, python?

Tags: python, web-scraping

Why am I getting this error ?

> Key error 'screen_name'
>
> module body in untitled at line 20
>
> df = df.loc[df['screen_name'] == user]

[image: screenshot]

```
from twitterscraper import query_tweets
from twitterscraper.query import query_tweets_from_user
import datetime as dt 
import pandas as pd 


begin_date = dt.date(2020,7,1)
end_date = dt.date(2020,7,13)


limit = 100
lang = 'english'

#Use this to search a specific user

user = 'realDonaldTrump'
tweets = query_tweets_from_user(user)
df = pd.DataFrame(t.__dict__ for t in tweets)

df = df.loc[df['screen_name'] == user]

df = df['text']

df
```

Comment: In the screenshot it says "key error 'screen_name' " so probably `df['screen_name']` has nothing with a key named `screen_name`. You should check the documentation and use the correct key value. Maybe `user`?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the tool isn't working for whatever reason. Call `assert len(df) > 0` before the line that gives you error - if there are no tweets - then you won't be able to select from that DataFrame, since it's empty.

You can try this other tool - `twitter_scraper` (notice the underscore):

```py
from twitter_scraper import get_tweets
import pandas as pd

user = 'realDonaldTrump'

df = pd.json_normalize(get_tweets(user, pages=1))
df = df[df.username == user]
df = df['text']
df
```

This produces:

```
2     Another one of many Fake T.V. Ads, this one ab...
13    Another one of many Fake T.V. Ads, this one ab...
17    THANK YOU @NAPOpolice and their 241,000 brave ...
18    ...be on the way, and Americans want safe stre...
Name: text, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you so much @avloss this one is shorter and cleaner, yet how can we get the full tweets? Can we search for keywords with twitter_scraper?

Comment: I tried this one but the result are random!            

`from twitter_scraper import get_tweets
for tweet in get_tweets('avloss', pages=1):
    print(tweet['text'])`

Comment: you can get full tweets by doing something like `print(df.tolist())` -links get cropped, but that's how they are shown in the actual tweet. I don't tweet much.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can search efficiently with a scraper tool, you might want to consider using Twitter API - something from here perhaps https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/developer-utilities/twitter-libraries You would need to open a developer account with twitter for that I would imagine.